# [Reinforcement Learning]Why does my reward become 0 and end? I have some trouble with gym environment

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, openai-api

everybody!

I have few trouble with my custom environment with openAI's gym.

I want to make a environment which accumulate the reward everytime 'pump' the balloon,

And if balloon burst, every reward become 0

I made a environment function 'step' and 'reward' like below

```
def step(self, action):
    assert self.action_space.contains(action)
    reward = self.reward
    if action: # pump a balloon or stop ( 1 / 0 )
        self.npumps += 1
        if burst(self.max_pump, self.npumps):
            self.balloon=1
            terminated = True
            reward = 0
        else:
            terminated = False
            reward =self.npumps
    else: # stop to pump balloon and withdraw rewards
        terminated = True
    
    if self.render_mode == "human":
        self.render()
    
    return self._get_obs(), reward, terminated, False, {}

def _get_obs(self):
    return ({"kth pump": self.npumps, "balloon": self.balloon})

def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
    super().reset(seed=seed)
    self.npumps = 0
    self.balloon = 0 # pop = 1, else = 0
    self.reward = 0
    return self._get_obs(), {}
```

however, when I use this function to simulate agent's behavior, it seems something go wrong.

```
done = False
obs = env.reset()
while not done:
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    obs, reward, done, _, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
    print(obs, action, reward)
env.close()
```

and then

{'kth pump': 1, 'balloon': 0} 1 1

{'kth pump': 2, 'balloon': 0} 1 2

{'kth pump': 3, 'balloon': 0} 1 3

{'kth pump': 3, 'balloon': 0} 0 0

Why does this happens?
Is this is correct function? or I did something wrong?
Am I misunderstood the mechanism of gym.env.step?

please give some tip for noob in this field!

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your `reset` method you set your class variable `self.reward = 0`. Then at the beginning of each `step` call you assign `reward = self.reward`, while never changing the right side, which is always 0 since its instantiation, so that your `reward` is also 0. Then if your action is 0, you only change your `terminated` flag to `True` and never assign anything else to `reward`, so that it of course remains 0.